# How can I get LAMP up and running with Debian?

Tags: debian, web-server, lamp, security

I [need](https://serverfault.com/questions/24158/best-free-operating-system-for-a-secure-home-web-server) to install [Debian](http://www.debian.org/) for a webserver on a dual-Xeon machine, and it must be as "secure" as possible, with whatever programs and features are available (Firewall, Antivirus, etc).

I need basic webserver functionality, with the LAMP stack *(where P is PHP)*, minus the FTP since I have constant physical access and I don't want to open a hole for attacks and unauthorized access.

1. What version/edition do I download, burn and install? I don't understand the myraid of editions.
2. How do I install/configure the LAMP stack (with admin panels) in order to get my server online?
3. How can I setup the software for maximum anti-hacker protection, especially for Databases?
4. Any dashboard and monitoring softwares that help in reading server performance/overloading?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Good questions. First, always install the latest Debian version (stable) and go from there. Choose the minimum install and after it is completed use apt-get to get the packages you need:

```
# apt-get install apache2
# apt-get install php5
# apt-get install mysql-server
```

That should get your LAMP ready (Linux + Apache + MySQL + PHP).

Since you mentioned maximum security, I will say to do not install any of these graphical tools to manage your server (like cpanel, webmin, etc). Apache + PHP + Mysql configuration is simple enough to do via the terminal (plus, they come almost pre-configured by default).

To monitor, I will suggest OSSEC (will monitor your logs, changes on your important files, etc).

Comment: Maybe could you elaborate on the configuration? Or at least link to a resource for it? I have done the configuration command-line many times, but don't remember offhand, and security can be hard to implement, especially without guidelines as to what needs to be watched for.

Comment: Just FYI, Debian (at least Etch) doesn't have apache2-mod-auth-mysql; in case you wanted to use that...

Comment: I just started playing with this in the lab for a possible migration of windows to Linux for a web server as well.  The download of debian server I had listed a LAMP install as part of the initial setup.  Why should I not use that instead of doing the minimum install and then going out and getting the LAMP packages like you suggest here?

Answer (score 3):

This is the only information you are going to need for installation.

http://www.howtoforge.com/perfect-server-debian-lenny-ispconfig3

As for Xeons, you probably want the i386 distro unless they are 64bit procs(can still get away with this).

Answer (score 3):

To address your security concern, I would install **iptables** and only allow port 80 (and 443 if necessary) to the public.

Then I would install **openvpn** (allow its port on the firewall as well), and do all of your management via a VPN connection.

Then stay on top of your security updates - have the system check the repositories every day and email you about all available updates, and apply them as soon as you are able.  For a LAMP stack I would also add the **dotdeb** repositories to your /etc/apt/sources.lst, as dotdeb stays much more on top of patching the latest php/apache/mysql vulnerabilities than *debian* does.